# Images not loading in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I can see the image in chrome and IE but not in Firefox.
On inspecting the image element, there is `display:none !important` assigned to it.

Not using any vendor CSS or JS files. It's plain HTML.
When I check the Media info in Firefox, I can see the image listed and the 'block' option is not marked.

What could be the reason and how to fix it.

```
<ul>
 <li>
   <a href="#">
     <img src="images/ad1.jpg"/>
   </a>
  </li>                    
 </ul>
```

[image]

**UPDATE**
I had an ad-blocker plugin in firefox which was causing this issue.
renaming the class `ads`, did not work, but renaming the image worked. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you have an adblock extension active, since your image is nested in a div with a class of `.ads`

Comment: ahhhh you were bang on. That never occurred to me.